# How to Play Sound File in Swift 2

Tags: swift, audio

I am using below code, but no sound is heard.

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SecondBeep", ofType: "wav")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }
    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer?.play()

}
```

AVFoundation is imported properly and sound file is added to the project. Checked other stackoverflow topics but it does not help.

Tried to change to `URLForResource` but it does not help, too.

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SecondBeep", withExtension: "wav")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!.path!)
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to "does not work"? Do you mean that it doesn't play?

Comment: Why don't you simply use URLForResource instead of pathForResource?

Comment: @Arc676, can not hear anything. I see print the file and player in console but nothing is heard.

Comment: @LeoDabus, tried it but it does not help, too.

Comment: @JohnBernard edit your post and show your actual code. Also make sure you copied the file to your project and check copy if needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let myAudioUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SecondBeep", withExtension: "wav") {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myAudioUrl)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a fresh project and added sound files and indeed your code works in Simulator. But when I send the app to my iPhone 6s Plus, it does not work. Any ideas for the issue? Is it security or permission issue to play local files in cell phone app?

Comment: OK I have to accept your answer because it is working with Simulator. Still could not work on my iPhone.

Comment: @JohnBernard If you don't figure it out please let me know

Comment: I am not sure. I checked the compiled .app file and the sound file is also there. Simulator plays the sound but iPhone does not.

Comment: Try isolating your problem creating a new sample project and drag your file from the finder and release it besides the swift files.  Check copy if needed checkbox

Comment: I used my iPad to test and the project works OK and plays the sound on iPad. So this makes the swift and project is OK. Any ideas why it does not work for my iPhone? Using latest iOS version. Restarted my phone.

Comment: @JohnBernard I have no idea. I would need to test the actual project to find out why it works only on the iPad

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!  // Global variable

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playVes()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func playVes() {
        do {
            self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("123", ofType: "mp3")!))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: @BalajiGupta, this is basically same with my code, is not it?

Comment: This is Swift 1 code, not Swift 2! OP's code example is in Swift 2... How come such a bad answer has upvotes? Sigh...

Comment: @BalajiGupta Do you know what is a  Global variable ?

Comment: its Global variable trough out in this view controller.